# layout that forces vertical bar to always touch footer

Tags: html, css

This fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/5BSva/17/

Shows a layout I am trying to achieve.  I want the vertical bar from the base of the tab to extend to the footer.

Here is what I need to accomplish...

1. In the initial state, no content is displayed, and the vertical bar correctly extends down to the footer.  The vertical bar should always extend to the footer.
2. When you toggle the content to show, notice the vertical bar does not extend to the footer.  The vertical bar needs to extend to the footer.
3. I want to accomplish this without the use of any image hacks.

Is there a way to change this fiddle so that the vertical bar always extends to the footer whether there is content that stretches the parent or not?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="body">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabcontrol">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" style="">
                <div class="navigation" style="">navigation
                    <br />navigation
                    <br />navigation
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <button id="toggle">Toggle Content</button>
                    <div id="theContent" style="display:none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In congue odio quis libero dapibus ut tincidunt lectus vestibulum. Donec quis ligula tortor. Sed adipiscing tempor elit, at porttitor lacus luctus ut. Suspendisse suscipit, orci bibendum tincidunt venenatis, lorem ligula aliquet felis, in fringilla diam velit eu sapien. Aliquam vitae varius lacus. Nullam cursus nibh at leo varius vestibulum. Maecenas cursus dui quis metus hendrerit a lacinia est eleifend. Donec pharetra pharetra libero, non tincidunt magna fringilla in. Nulla convallis ornare dui, sed vestibulum turpis rutrum vestibulum. Duis convallis, eros nec vulputate congue, velit elit scelerisque purus, ut ultricies eros felis ac justo.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer center">
    <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201); background-color: #fff;"></div>
    <div>FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.body {
    border: 1px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-top: 5px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-left: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}
/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px auto;
    /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 50px;
    /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
    clear: both;
}
form {
    height: 100%;
}
/* Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait (http://ryanfait.com/) */
.navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    border-right: 3px solid rgb(174, 174, 201);
    padding-top: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    top:65px;
}
.content {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left:160px;
}
.nav {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**'

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle').click(function () {
        $('#theContent').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What browser are you viewing this in. As it looks fine in chrome from what i can see

Comment: try to give border to right content than navigation assuming that navigation will never be longer than content

Comment: And initially you need to give a minimum height to content too

Comment: @Andrew - I am using Chrome as well.  If you click the button, you will see the problem.

Comment: @anpsmn - I can't make this assumption.  The nav could be longer than the content, or the content could be longer than the nav.  I am trying to develop a UI pattern that will be used in multiple situations.

Comment: Then you can use the [Faux Columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns) trick

Comment: @anpsmn - See #3.  No image hacks.  I think the Faux Columns trick is an image hack.

Comment: Oh Sorry! I forgot about it. Maybe this [link](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) helps. It says `The third and final way which this post investigates uses pure CSS and doesn't require any background images, at least initially.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is JS an option? I do this all the time:

Add an ID to your navigation and your content divs

```
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    $('#theContent').toggle(0,function(){
        $('#navigation').height($('#content').height());
    });
});
```

It would need a little finessing to work for you such as finding the minimum height when the text is hidden and picking up window resize events and adjusting accordingly, but it should work for you.

Comment: I think this is workable.  For anyone who is interested, I have an updated fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/5BSva/23/) that demonstrates the use of the idea presented above.